# When i run the play framework with sbt some error

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

My operating system is Windows 10pro, I downloaded the Play framework 2.3 without activator. I tried to build it by sbt (version 1.3.13), jdk version 1.8.
When I am under the Helloword directory:

I run sbt and the error is:

```
C:\Git\Helloworld>sbt
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sbt.StringUtilities$.nonEmpty(StringUtilities.scala:14)
        at sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID.$percent(DependencyBuilders.scala:50)
        at $39db74d36cbf6131c890$.$sbtdef(C:\Git\Helloworld\project\plugins.sbt:8)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$.getValue(Eval.scala:420)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:87)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:87)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSetting$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:150)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSetting$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:148)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:110)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:110)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:507)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:502)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:501)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:501)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.Load$.loadSettings$1(Load.scala:500)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expand$1(Load.scala:523)
        at sbt.Load$.loadSettings(Load.scala:528)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSbtFiles$1(Load.scala:464)
        at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:475)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I tried to fix it but bad results.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your `build.sbt`

Comment: Specially on the line `C:\Git\Helloworld\project\plugins.sbt:8`

Comment: name := "helloworld"

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := Option(System.getProperty("scala.version")).getOrElse("2.10.4")

Comment: // Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % System.getProperty("play.version"))

Comment: @LisaErba Play 2.6.6 is the first version that supports sbt 1.x.